# Google Drive link sharing using Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, storage, drive

I want my Java code to generate Google Drive share links to certain files. I have seen posts which explained how to do it by using other programming languages, but I could not find anything about doing that in Java. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Google drive Java API. Check out this link
https://o7planning.org/en/11889/manipulating-files-and-folders-on-google-drive-using-java

Comment: I see there sharing for a public and sharing for a certain user. But how to generate a link to a file which is available to everyone?

Comment: Can you answer my question?